# How to know the equation of the fitting curve

Tags: python, regression, curve-fitting

I'd like to ask,
How to know the equation of the fitting curve? especially in degree 3.
So I fit my data using regression linear with degree 3.
I'd like to split the fitting curve into separate figure.

```
    # Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
# we use orde 2 for our Polynomial
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

poly_reg1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree= 1)
x_poly1 = poly_reg1.fit_transform(x1)
pol_reg1 = LinearRegression()
pol_reg1.fit(x_poly1, y1)

poly_reg2 = PolynomialFeatures(degree= 3)
x_poly2 = poly_reg2.fit_transform(x2)
pol_reg2 = LinearRegression()
pol_reg2.fit(x_poly2, y2)
    
# find R2 value 
y_poly_pred1=pol_reg1.predict(x_poly1)
r2_1 = r2_score(x1,y_poly_pred1)

y_poly_pred2=pol_reg2.predict(x_poly2)
r2_2 = r2_score(x2,y_poly_pred2)

# Visualizing the Polymonial Regression results
plt.scatter(x1, y1, color='blue')
plt.plot(x1, pol_reg1.predict(poly_reg1.fit_transform(x1)), color='magenta')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, color='black')
plt.plot(x2, pol_reg2.predict(poly_reg2.fit_transform(x2)), color='red')

plt.title('EAN vs ln I_m')
plt.xlabel('EAN')
plt.ylabel('ln I_m')
plt.show()

print('r2_1 is '+ str(r2_1))
print('r2_2 is '+ str(r2_2))
```

Comment: Clarification question: do you need the equation per se or just to be able to draw the model?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to draw the models (and assuming `x1` and `x2` are 1-D), you can get it with

```
xg = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 300)
plt.plot(xg, pol_reg1.predict(poly_reg1.transform(xg)), color='magenta')
plt.plot(xg, pol_reg2.predict(poly_reg2.transform(xg)), color='red')
```

where `xmin` and `xmax` denote the minimum and maximum values between which you want you model drawn.